# How routing for pages like support.domain.com can be created in express.js routing?

Tags: node.js, express

I wonder how webpages like support.domain.com created?

I have below code which creates routing like 
domain.com/support.

Any answer will be really helpful.

```
app.use('/support' ,express.static(path.join(__dirname,'support')));
```

Do I need to own the domain support.domain.com ? I already own the domain.com

Comment: Yes, you need to own `support.domain.com`.   Once you own that domain, it is possible to configure it to go to your same express server, yet have separate routing.

Comment: but I think it is not possible to search and buy this type of domain ?

Comment: It's called a subdomain. Adding subdomains is free because you already purchased the domain. And if you bought your domain from one of those kind of registras that are shady just point your domain at a free DNS provider that isn't shady.

Comment: When you own `domain.com`, adding `support.domain.com` is something your DNS service provider can configure for you.  It's called a sub-domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an third party model named "[express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain)"

And apply it as of one of your Express middleware

```js
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const supportRoute = require('./routes/support');

app.use(subdomain('support', supportRoute));
```

[Development]

And don't forget you modify your `/etc/hosts/`

```
localhost 127.0.0.1
support.yourapp.local 127.0.0.1
```

[Production]

And for production, you have to add a new a record for your DNS domain